# Why wouldn't an imported theme's variables be working?

Tags: css, asp.net, bootstrap-5

I've been banging my face against my monitor for hours trying to figure out this issue that seemingly no one else is experiencing, so here we are.
I'm learning ASP.NET and working on using themes from bootswatch in my CSS folder. The bootswatch and bootstrap versions are the same (5.1.3), but the code is broken anywhere that involves a variable in the CSS file that I brought in. I'm only going to be using screenshots in this post because the files are huge and the error is what's important.
Additional info:
All packages/extensions are up to date, all variables are declared and initialized in the CSS file, and here is a link to the theme I'm trying to use: https://bootswatch.com/darkly/
Thanks for any help anyone can provide.
[image]
[image]

and my _Layout file looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - LearningAspNetWebApp</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/darklyTheme.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true"/>
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <!-- The following is copied and pasted from bootswatch Solar theme to trick out the nav bar-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarColor02" aria-controls="navbarColor02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarColor02">
                <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" asp-area="" asp-controller="Category" asp-action="Index">Category</a>
                    </li>
                    @*<li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>*@
                </ul>
                <form class="d-flex">
                    <input class="form-control me-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- End Trick Out-->
</header>
<div class="container">
    <main role="main" class="pb-3">
        @RenderBody()
    </main>
</div>

<footer class="border-top footer text-muted">
    <div class="container">
        &copy; 2022 - LearningAspNetWebApp - <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
    </div>
</footer>
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
@await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my folder structure:
[image]

Comment: Could be browser cache. When you change the css source files, the browser does NOT detect this, and will OFTEN cache the css. So, if you make a change to the css file(s) in question? Then either after the page loads, hit ctrl-f5 on your browser - it should detect the css changes. If not, then go nuclear, and close the browser page (and your running app), and then in browser, empty out the cache - everything - now try again. As noted, usually a simple ctrl-f5 to force a  re-load refresh will work, but give this a try. Blew out and wasted a whole day first time I was hit by this cache issue.

Comment: The above comment will help when you don't see css changes - the comments however do not deal with you modifying the css and JavaScript files - that is a big  and different issue. - one I don't have a solution for right now.

Comment: Yeah, it's mainly just not recognizing the variables. They're all declared and initialized in the :root pseudoclass, and everything is structured just fine. It's just all "Whoooaaaa, what is all THIS??"

Comment: .NET won't compile SCSS/SASS on runtime so you will need to compile the style file. Either do that with a third party tool or an approach like this: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/use-sass-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application-207811b61048

Comment: @EgilHansen I'm going to try that, thanks. If only to get it working. But it seems strange that everywhere I look, different folks are just adding the css file to the css folder and everything is working out great. I just wonder what they have going on that I don't

Comment: @EgilHansen Check this out: I put the downloaded css theme into lib>bootstrap>dist>css along with all the others and nothing was broken anymore. So, it's... fixed.. This is one of the worst scenarios, because I fixed it, but I still don't understand why or how

Comment: Wow, that's weird :O Is the CSS theme file still uncompiled? Anyways happy that you got it working :) Always frustrating with problems like this!